# can we use Exoplayer for Websites?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am working on an AWS cloud project which involves video streaming. For this case, a media player needs be to used is Exoplayer along with required AWS services but I am not able to find anything regarding Exoplayer's use on Websites. Can anyone help me with the usage of Exoplayer for web applications?

Answer (score 1):

ExoPlayer is an Android player - for websites, you would typically use a HTML5/JavaScript player assuming your service is using a typical video streaming technology such as HLS or DASH.

OpenSource HTML5/JavaScript players are readily available:

- https://github.com/videojs/video.js
- https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player

There are also multiple commercial players also like BitMovin, TheoPlayer, JWPlayer etc.

Comment: thank you for quick response, this information helped!!